# How to detect a user login failure on a mac?

Tags: python, macos, authentication

**I intend to have a program detect when a login failure occurs.** I intend to use this program on mac, in case that is important. Could this solution detect how many login failures occur, or would I use a variable to determine how many have occurred?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322763/how-do-i-see-all-my-failed-login-attempts-macos-high-sierra, Try to scrap data from your log files add them to a list or a dict if you want to separate the data, time etc, and run a for loop to do whatever you want with the data. I wont be able to provide the code as I am not a mac user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @JaniniRami, you can scrape the data from the macOS logs located in `/var/log/asl.log` (except for macOS High Sierra), and see if there were any authentication failures in the log (such as warnings or errors)

Comment: How would one locate the macOS logs on macOS High Sierra?

Comment: Try this: https://www.howtogeek.com/356942/how-to-view-the-system-log-on-a-mac/